# Unable to create bot using AWS Lex Api

Tags: amazon-web-services, bots

currently , i'm develop chatbot platform using lex but whenever i tried create the bot it always give me an error response

Here is my code

```
 @lex = Aws::LexModelBuildingService::Client.new
    params =
    {
      "name": "TestBot",
      "abortStatement": {
          "messages": [
              {
                  "content": "Sorry, I'm not able to assist at this time",
                  "contentType": "PlainText"
              }
          ]
      },
       "child_directed": true,
       "clarificationPrompt": {
          "maxAttempts": 3,
          "messages": [
             {
               "content": "I didn't understand you, what would you like to do?",
               "contentType": "PlainText"
             }
          ]
       },
       "description": "Test Bot ",
       "idleSessionTTLInSeconds": 600,
       "locale": "en-US",
       "voiceId": "Salli"
    }
    @lex.put_bot(params)
```

The Errors

```
ArgumentError: parameter validator found 4 errors:
  - unexpected value at params[:abortStatement]
  - unexpected value at params[:clarificationPrompt]
  - unexpected value at params[:idleSessionTTLInSeconds]
  - unexpected value at params[:voiceId]
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , i figure out the solution. the key should be written in lowercase and each word must separated with "_" . Here is the code for params

```
{
  "name": "TestBot",
  "abort_statement": {
      "messages": [
          {
              "content": "Sorry, I'm not able to assist at this time",
              "content_type": "PlainText"
          }
      ]
  },
   "child_directed": true,
   "clarification_prompt": {
      "max_attempts": 3,
      "messages": [
         {
           "content": "I didn't understand you, what would you like to do?",
           "content_type": "PlainText"
         }
      ]
   },
   "description": "Test Bot ",
   "idle_session_ttl_in_seconds": 600,
   "locale": "en-US",
   "voice_id": "Salli"
}
```